# Error with heroku run rake db:migrate - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/db/schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, migrate

I was trying to get my project working on Heroku but when I was trying to run "rake db:migrate" got the following

any idea????

Thanks :)

P.D: I think the probles is here

> ```
> ** Execute db:schema:dump
> rake aborted!
> ```

Because

> Rake tasks that write to disk, such as rake db:schema:dump, are not compatible with Heroku’s ephemeral filesystem.

---

```
   PS C:\Users\siel3\Documents\nimbus> heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.6524
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /app/db/schema.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:243:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:243:in `open'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:243:in `block (3 levels)
 in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:50:in `block (2 levels)
in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:45:in `block (2 levels)
in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have a db/schema.rb file in your application?  That file should be in ApplicationName/db/schema.rb  If this is your first upload to heroku maybe try to run rake db:seed first to create the schema file, then do your migrations after.

Comment: Yes, the file is there, the application runs locally without problems. I Tried  to run "heroku run rake db:seed" before but the error keeps the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Windows...

Windows rename the `/db` folder as `/DB`, and heroku breaks if this happens.